# VBA code to find out maximum value in a range and add 1 to the value in the other cell

Tags: vba, excel, max

You may find this question little strange but I need this really for my calculation worksheet.

Firstly, I will post my requirement then based on the request I will share my VBA code. However, its built very poorly.

I need a VBA code that will find Maximum value in a range (I11 to I21) and taking this value, I have to add 1 (+1) in to the other cell that is "G2".

Please help me to get a code for this. Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you post an example table? a before and after would be best

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go with a simple 1 line solution:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Range("G2") =  WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("I11:I21")) + 1
End Sub
```

OR

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Range("G2") = Range("G2") +  WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("I11:I21")) + 1
End Sub
```

depending on what exactly do you want to do.

Comment: Hi Vityata,

Thanks a lot for the rapid response. 

It worked absolutely fine and met my requirement. I also need additional favour from this code to use it in future.

I would like to have an IF statement in this vba code. Like if the max value is not greater than range G2, then it should fire the above macro.

Is it possible?

Comment: @Sarathkumar - you are welcome. In general, it is better if you always share your VBA code in the question. It does not matter that you think that it is bad. You may select my answer as accepted.

Comment: I just mapped almost one page full of codes using help from my colleagues and some searched from net also used some of my learning. Its way too big to paste  it here. 
But, with your above code, I have added IF functionality, now its works absolutely perfect. Thanks for helping me out. 

    Public Sub TestMe()
    If Range("G2") > WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("I11:I21")) Then
    Range("G2") = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("I11:I21")) + 1
    End Sub

Comment: @Sarathkumar - thumbs up! :)

Comment: Hi Vityata, Again just one more question. I am not that great to work with VBA code. But could you just tell me.. In order to run this code simply in worksheet after entering value in G2, in which event I can put this?

Comment: @Sarathkumar - try with selection_change - https://pastebin.com/ygbg8TGr

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot. Finally, worksheet come to an stage where I can concentrate on other things.

Answer (score 0):

I just mapped almost one page full of codes using help from my colleagues and some searched from net also used some of my learning. Its way too big to paste  it here. 
But, with your above code, I have added IF functionality, now its works absolutely perfect. Thanks for helping me out.

```
Public Sub TestMe()
If Range("G2") > WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("I11:I21")) Then
Range("G2") = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("I11:I21")) + 1
End Sub
```